# Rails, не сохраняется новый объект в базу

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Есть модели User, Articles, Comments. Использую свзязь has_many :through когда Comments привязан к User и Articles.

Отправляю комментарий, ни каких ошибок не получаю (страница перезагружается), в базе тоже чисто.

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
  def create
    @article = Article.find(params[:article_id])
    logger.debug "@ARTICLE VAL: #{@article.attributes.inspect}"
    @comment = @article.comments.create(comment_params)
    logger.debug "@COMMENT PARAMS: #{comment_params.inspect}"
    redirect_to article_path(@article)
  end
  private
  def comment_params
    params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
  end
end
```

В логах:

```
Started POST "/articles/6/comments" for 127.0.0.1 at 2017-02-06 13:14:56 +0200
Processing by CommentsController#create as HTML
Parameters: {"utf8"=>"✓", "authenticity_token"=>"***", "comment"=>{"body"=>"11111"}, 
"commit"=>"Create Comment", "article_id"=>"6"}
[1m[36mArticle Load (3.2ms)[0m  [1m[34mSELECT  "articles".* FROM "articles" 
WHERE "articles"."id" = ? LIMIT ?[0m  [["id", 6], ["LIMIT", 1]]
@ARTICLE VAL: {"id"=>6, "title"=>"Article 4", "text"=>"qwer", 
"created_at"=>Mon, 06 Feb 2017 05:25:11 UTC +00:00, 
"updated_at"=>Mon, 06 Feb 2017 05:25:11 UTC +00:00, "user_id"=>1}
[1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mbegin transaction[0m
[1m[35m (0.1ms)[0m  [1m[36mcommit transaction[0m
@COMMENT PARAMS: <ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"11111"} permitted: true>
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/articles/6
Completed 302 Found in 14ms (ActiveRecord: 3.4ms)
```

В чем дело?

---

Добавил модель

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :article
  belongs_to :user
end
```

Comment: попробуйте заменить `create` на `create!` и посмотрите ошибку

Comment: Получаю Validation failed: User must exist @comment = @article.comments.create!(comment_params)

Comment: вот вам и ответ.

Comment: Я его честно говоря не понимаю, пользователь у меня один в логе его ид есть "user_id"=>1, что значит его не существует, если он есть?

Comment: добавьте модель `Comments` в вопрос

Comment: Добавил в тело.

Comment: Что в `comment_params`?

Comment: Он в CommentsController добавил в тело. В логах comment_params выводит @COMMENT PARAMS: <ActionController::Parameters {"body"=>"11111"} permitted: true>

Comment: Хотя зря спросил, он был не нужен .-. Нет у вас там `user_id`. Он есть у статьи, а у комментария нет.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У вас там валидация грохнулась. Мол, комментарий должен принадлежать пользователю. Требование вполне осмысленное. Отсюда вопрос:

### Кто отправляет комментарий-то?

#### У вас ни один пользователь в контроллере не упоминается.

Проследите за тем, какие поля у вас заполняются в новом комментарии.

- В `comment_params` вы забираете только `body`.
- Из ассоциации `@article.comments` вы получите внешний ключ статьи.

  - `article_id`, скорее всего.

Откуда в комментарий попадёт `user_id`?

Нужно как-то его туда добавить.

---

Можно создавать комментарий не в одной ассоциации, а в их смеси с помощью `merge`, примерно так:

```
@comment = @article.comments
                   .merge(current_user.comments) # <---- добавилось
                   .create(comment_params)
```

Это, конечно, при условии, что `current_user` у вас возвращает текущего залогиненного пользователя, и у него есть правильный `has_many :comments`.

---

Можно привинтить этот параметр в `comment_params`. Это проще осознать, но это строит лишнее предположение о том, как называется колонка с внешним ключом автора комментария.

```
params.require(:comment)
      .permit(:body)
      .merge(user_id: current_user.id) # <----
```

Опять же, я рассчитываю, что `current_user.id` в вашем приложении имеет смысл (что скорее всего так, а если нет, то вы скорее всего об этом знаете).

---

Можно использовать какой бы там ни было другой способ, который приведёт к заданию в комментарии поля `user_id`.

Comment: Спасибо, 2 вариант мне понравился больше, теперь все работает. Я думал раз в @article отсвечивает "user_id"=>1 то он как то попадает в комментарий.

Comment: @SergeiR и вышло бы, что комментарии к статье пишутся её автором и только им, правда восхитительно? :D